# How to compile 'stygmorgan-0.29'?

Tags: command-line, compiling, install-from-source, make

I am trying to compile `stygmorgan-0.29.tar.bz2` and got these messages:

```
stygmorganui.cxx:7:28: fatal error: stygmicon128.xpm: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [stygmorganui.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/papa/Downloads/stygmorgan-0.29/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/papa/Downloads/stygmorgan-0.29/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
papa@papa-G31-M7-TE:~/Downloads/stygmorgan-0.29$
```

Comment: Could you show us **all** the output? Also, from what place did you downloaded the package (link)?

Answer (score 0):

This file is missing: **stygmicon128.xpm**

It's an icon, if it isn't present into the original package, just use any other icon.

In [this link](http://developer.berlios.de/forum/forum.php?forum_id=21428) you can find more details about the same problem

Answer (score 0):

#### Try the updated version 0.29.1

On the [project page](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/stygmorgan/) you can see that 0.29 has been superseded by 0.29.1. Doing a diff on both releases I see the error in the original 0.29 version:

```
$ diff -r -q stygmorgan-0.29 stygmorgan-0.29.1
[...]
Only in stygmorgan-0.29.1/src: stygmicon128.xpm
[...]
```

Wherever you got that download from, please inform the poster/webmaster it is faulty and the link should be updated to point to the release with the fix.